# How Bagging in LightGBM works

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm

In the lightGBM model, there are 2 parameters related to bagging

```
bagging_fraction
bagging_freq (frequency for bagging
              0 means disable bagging; k means perform bagging at every k 
              iteration
              Note: to enable bagging, bagging_fraction should be set to 
              value smaller than 1.0 as well)
```

I could find some more detailed explanation about this bagging function in gdbt. So is there anybody give me a more detailed explaination?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code executes what documentation says- it samples a subset of training examples of the size `bagging_fraction * N_train_examples`. And training of the i-th tree is performed on this subset. This sampling can be done for each tree (i.e. each iteration) or after each `bagging_freq` trees have been trained.

For example, `bagging_fraction=0.5, bagging_freq=10` means that sampling of new `0.5*N_train_examples` entries will happen every 10 iterations

Comment: Does this mean that a lower bagging_frequency will result in less overfitting?

Comment: When one looks at 2 extrema: `bagging_freq=1` and `bagging_freq=<the number oftrees in your model>`, then yes, the latter option will lead to more overfitting. However, it doesn't mean that small differences in the parameter lead to a strong advantage, e.g. that the model with `bagging_freq=2` will be much more overfitted than with `bagging_freq=1`. As long as `bagging_freq << <the number oftrees in your model>` you should be good

Comment: with or without replacement?

Comment: Without.
From the [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters-Tuning.html#use-bagging): _"This process of training over multiple random samples **without replacement** is called “bagging”."_